# in_array() does not work as expected

Tags: php, arrays

For this array `($options)`:

```
Array (
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
)
```

PHP returns TRUE:

```
$this->assertTrue( in_array('Bug', $options ) );         // TRUE
$this->assertTrue( in_array('Feature', $options ) );     // TRUE
$this->assertTrue( in_array('Task', $options ) );        // TRUE
$this->assertTrue( in_array('RockAndRoll', $options ) ); // TRUE
```

Why?

Comment: @Phil: Oh yep, thought so, deleted it before I saw your response.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is because [`0 == "string"` is true](http://php.net/manual/types.comparisons.php), and `0` is an element of the array.

Set the parameter `$strict` in `in_array` to true:

```
$this->assertTrue( in_array('Bug', $options, true) );
```

Answer (score 6):

Try adding a third parameter to your function calls;

```
$this->assertTrue( in_array('Bug', $options, true) );
```

This will ensure the comparisons are type-strict, and should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Add a third argument to `in_array()` and set it to `TRUE`.