# in_array comparing two different types and yet returning true

Tags: php

I have a real mystery on my hands..

Behold the following lines of code..

```
if (in_array($_SESSION['enemies'][$i], $clones[$j]->defendAgainst)) {
    ..
}
```

where $_SESSION['enemies'][$i] is an object of something like:

```
object(skinhead)#4 (16) 
 {
 ["weapon"]=> object(bowieknife)#5 (2)
 { ["name":protected]=> NULL ["damage":protected]=> NULL }
 ["name"]=> string(8) "skinhead" 
 ["health"]=>string(3) "100"
 ["strength"]=> string(2) "10" 
 ["luck"]=> string(1) "2"
 ["money"]=>string(1) "0" 
 ["exp"]=> string(1) "0" 
 ["rank"]=> string(2) "20" 
 ["points"]=> string(1)"0" 
 ["location_id"]=> NULL 
 ["comboAttack"]=> int(2) 
 ["attackValue"]=> int(15) 
 ["attackType"]=> NULL 
 ["attackMessage"]=> string(198) "Enemy #1 pulls off a 2-hit combo.Enemy #1 slashes at you with a bowie knife.You defend.You lose 8 health.Enemy #1 slashes at you with a bowie knife." 
 ["target1"]=> NULL ["target2"]=> NULL }
```

and $clones[$j]->defendAgainst is an array of ints

Now in_array should evaluate to false, since it is searching for an object in an array of ints. But instead it returns true!!!! How can this be?????

Comment: Please make your question readable.

Comment: How is it not readable?....

Comment: @user2361103: Your object is all in one line.

Comment: the contents of the object are not really the point of my question....the point is the object is NOT an int, i included the var_dump to emphasize this fact...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for php to compare an object to an int, it will cast the object to an int, and then do the comparison.

```
$new = (int) $someObject;
var_dump($new); // int 1
var_dump($new == 1); // true, obviously.
```

in_array() uses == by default for comparisons.

...and my magic crystal ball tells me your array of ints contains an integer with value 1.

Comment: +1 and lol, I've done just so many times `if ($Obj) { /* Something */ }` that I don't know how I didn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

That is the expected output, you need to add a third value as TRUE to make it also compare the types, as can be seen in the PHP manual for [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )
```

The third value is default to FALSE, but you can change that with a simple:

```
if (in_array($_SESSION['enemies'][$i], $clones[$j]->defendAgainst, TRUE))
```

EDIT: I think I know how you can find the problem yourself. I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11743527/). Try changing the in_array() to the form of the foreach() of the first answer, but change the `return TRUE;` like this to see what it brings:

```
foreach ($clones[$j]->defendAgainst as &$member) {
  if ($member == $_SESSION['enemies'][$i]) {
    var_dump($_SESSION['enemies'][$i]);
    var_dump($member);
  }
}
```

Comment: but how is it returning true in the first place, in order to return true it must be comparing SOMETHING....this is what im confused about!

Comment: Completely true, I gave my 2 cents but I'm not sure how to answer that second part. I edit this in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for accepting, but can you comment on it too, please? Now I'm also curious about it (;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669589/why-php-in-array-returns-true-when-it-shouldnt?rq=1......your intial answer was correct about the third variable but it still didnt explain why it was returning true...

Comment: That was funny as I've actually used it but didn't see it.